# Getting to wrong day of the week when using the object java.util.Date

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrive a date from a datePicker and create a java.util.Date Object and i don't understand why i'm getting the wrong day of the week in the **selectedDate** variable. The **currentDate** variable is correct.

```
String dateStr =  String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear) + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
String timeStr = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Date selectedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr + " " + timeStr);
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

System.out.println("selectedDate = " + String.valueOf(selectedDate));
System.out.println("currentDate  = " + String.valueOf(currentDate));
```

Output:

```
selectedDate = Mon Jun 13 12:44:00 WEST 2016
currentDate  = Wed Jul 13 12:44:04 WEST 2016
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check (print or debug) value of `monthOfYear` - the output shows that its value is 6 when you seem to expect it to be 7 (probably because you haven't accounted for the fact that `datePicker.getMonth()` returns a value between 0 and 11).

Since you don't show how you obtained the value it's hard to say much more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int[] date = {
        c.get(Calendar.DATE), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
        c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
};

date[1]+=1;
```

This setup uses the Calendar class, which is integrated into Android. date[1] += 1 is required in order to get the accurate month as the index on it goes from 0-11. All the others are fine as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

it actually looks for me, that a some point you start to count from '0' and on the other from '1'.

maybe try to pass the strings to the console for debugging first.